# Facebook multiple device login issue

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have used facebook sdk v 4.+ in android.
M facing issue in facebook login 
When i am  doing facebook login in my app from ios platform and after that using same account credentials m trying to login in android platform it  doesnt work. Its giving invalid hash key error.
For login to work i have to manually removed my app from facebook app settings.
When m removing my app from facebook account settings and doing login in android platform it works.
Plz help me with this issue.

Comment: Your question is very poorly written. I tried editing it to be able to read it better, but I can't understand anything past the first sentence.

Comment: Ok as I understand by your queries in your app, you can login in iOS easily but when you tried with Android same login in facebook then you are getting issues of hash key

Comment: Yes when i manually delete my app from ios then only i can able to login in android

Comment: @Treyten Carey : Are you clear questions now.?